# Automatic wrap (line wrap) or manual linebreak in Tikz fancytitle

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, tikz-styles, minipage, line-spacing

For a Tikz Fancytitle, how do I either:

1. Get automatic line wrapping,
   or
2. If 1. is not possible, add manual line breaks (say, using \\)

I used a nested minipage in this example but the question applies to titles on the Tikz box on outer level minipages as well!

Thanks!

**Current output:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\advance\topmargin-.8in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\paperheight1.5in 
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}
    

\begin{document}

\begin{center}{\huge{\textbf{Notes}}}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols*}{3}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries]

%------------ Box1 ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \small
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    
    %------------ Inner Box ---------------
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
        \small
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \end{minipage}
    };
    \node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {This is a really long title.\With a second sentence. And another sentence. And one more.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Box 1};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should sort the packages and also only put those packages in your MWE that are really needed. Apart from that, load some packages twice (such as `amsmath`) and you should load `hyperref` last. To your concrete question: Since you place the text inside a `\href` macro, it will be a bit more difficult to put line breaks here. Are these `\href` commands necessary?

Comment: Try `{\parbox{\columnwidth-30pt}{This is a really ....`

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes, \href{} is definitely not necessary. I accidentally left it in there. I edited and removed it. I’ve also updated the package list to be more compact.

Comment: @SimonDispa I’ve removed the \href{}. The \parbox on the base sentence only, does not seem to work. See:  https://imgur.com/a/nhbdwLW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If don't use these `\href` macros inside the nodes, which would prevent line breaking, you can use the `align` option together with manual line breaking using `\\` like so (I removed unnessesary packages and optimized the order of the packages):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}

\advance\topmargin-.8in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\paperheight1.5in 
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}{\huge{\textbf{Notes}}}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols*}{3}

\tikzset{mybox/.style={draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt},
        fancytitle/.style={fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries}
    }

%------------ Title ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \small
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    
    %------------ Title ---------------
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
        \small
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \end{minipage}
    };
    \node[fancytitle, right=10pt, align=left] at (box.north west) {This is a really long title. With a second sentence. \\ And another sentence. And one more.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Box 1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use the option `text width` (`text width=8cm` for example) for automatic line breaking, but then the node would always have the same width, regardless of the length of the text inside.

Comment: Thank you! Both options you gave will be perfect. I may use the latter since I don’t mind the node always having the same width (it will be filled with text always).